# Find a particular intermediate field $M$ such that $\mathbb{Q}\subset M\subset\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{\frac{3+i\sqrt{7}}{2}})$.

Tags: galois-theory, extension-field, galois-extensions, normal-extension

**Problem**: Let $\alpha=\sqrt{\frac{3+i\sqrt{7}}{2}}$ and $K=\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$. Find the fixed field $M=\{x\in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{\frac{3+i\sqrt{7}}{2}})|\sigma(x)=x\}$, where $\sigma$ is the automorphism on $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{\frac{3+i\sqrt{7}}{2}})$ such that $\sigma(\alpha)=\frac{2}{\alpha}$.

**My Attempt**: Note $\alpha$ and $\frac{\alpha}{2}$ are roots of $f(t)=t^4-3t^2+4$ and $K$ is the splitting field of $f(t)$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. By the *Fundamental Theorem of Galois Theory*, it is easy to see that such a $\sigma$ in the Galois group of $K: \mathbb{Q}$ indeed exists.

Now, every $x\in K$ has the form $x=p+q\alpha+r\alpha^2+s\alpha^3$, where $p, q, r, s\in\mathbb{Q}$, because $K: \mathbb{Q}$ is a simple algebraic extension. Thus $\sigma(x)=x\implies p+q\alpha+r\alpha^2+s\alpha^3=\sigma(p)+q\sigma(\alpha)+r\sigma^2(\alpha)+s\sigma^3(\alpha)=p+\frac{2q}{\alpha}+\frac{4r}{\alpha^2}+\frac{8s}{\alpha^3}$.

**My Question**: I failed to transform $p+\frac{2q}{\alpha}+\frac{4r}{\alpha^2}+\frac{8s}{\alpha^3}$ into the form of $p+q\alpha+r\alpha^2+s\alpha^3$. Any pointer would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It must be $\;f(t)=t^4-3t^2+4\;$ ...

Comment: @DonAntonio Indeed-thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: What is L? L is given in the problem.

Comment: @LawrenceMano My apologies-edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiply by $\;a^3\;$ in the identity you got and use $\;a^4=3a^2-4\;$:

$$p+qa+ra^2+sa^3=p+\frac{2q}a+\frac{4r}{a^2}+\frac{8s}{a^3}\stackrel{\cdot a^3}\implies$$

$$qa^4+ra^5+sa^6=2qa^2+4ra+8s\implies3qa^2-4q+3ra^3-4ra+s(3a^4-4a^2)=2qa^2+4ra+8s$$

$$\implies3qa^2-4q+3ra^3-4ra+s(5a^2-12)=2qa^2+4ra+8s\implies$$

$$\implies3ra^3+(q+5s)a^2-8ra-4(q+5s)=0$$

The last equality is possible iff $\;r=0\,,\,\,q=-5s\;$ , so your element is of the form

$$x=p-5sa+sa^3$$

Try now to take it from here...

Comment: Much appreciated!